# what would be the best way to include .tif image to pdflatex document?

Tags: graphics, pdftex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflat)

I'm trying to include .tif image to a pdflatex document, but it says it is unknown extension. what would be the best way to include .tif image to my pdflatex document?

Comment: You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to `convert` from `.tif` to some other format: `.png`, or `.jpg`.  You can use [Using macros in \DeclareGraphicsRule statement using shell command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66943/using-macros-in-declaregraphicsrule-statement-using-shell-command) to provide some automation of this process if this is something that you need to do often.

Comment: Related Question: [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflat), and [including tif/eps/pdf fails due to bounding box/dimensions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55666/including-tif-eps-pdf-fails-due-to-bounding-box-dimensions).

Comment: I'm closing as a dupe: the issue here is that pdfTeX does not read `.tif` files, which is covered in the answer I've linked to.