# How to include .tif pictures via pdftex?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, tiff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflat)

I am in the process of writing a paper for submission to PLOS ONE. Under their manuscript guidelines, they write that all photos (termed "half-tones") have to be submitted as tiff files.

How do I include tiff files in latex? At the moment my minimal example looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\title{hep}
\author{hep}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figurer/artifact.tif}

\end{document}
```

Compiling it with texlive I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .tif.
```

Most threads I come across simply advice the user to change the image format, but that is not really an option here. It would be preferable if the fix also worked with elsarticle.

Comment: Tiff are not supported anymore, convert the TIF to say uncompressed PNG. Many journals mention TIF in their requrements, but I have never seen anyone who complained if we used PNG instead

Comment: A [similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79632) was closed as a dupe of [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072)

Comment: By default, the most common LaTeX distributions such as TeX Live and MikTeX do not support .tiff images natively. However, you can still include .tiff images in your LaTeX document by converting them to a supported format such as .jpg or .png.