# Can you show the way how to add the .tif to latex?

Tags: graphics, tiff

I can convert the `.tif` to `.eps` or `.png`, but the requirement of my documents needs me to supply `.tif` images. To make sure the images keep the same, I would like to put the `.tif` images. Does anyone know how to add the these images to the document?

Please show me the code, not the explanation of how latex works.
Thank you.

Comment: most  back ends used with tex can not include tiff files, so you need to convert (to eps or png or pdf or whatever works) it is not clear what you mean by your requirement other than sending the original tiff file along with the document. whatever format you use, that format is not really still in the final generated pdf document, including the image implies some level of conversion to pdf.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add tif image to LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89989/add-tif-image-to-latex)

Comment: Thank you David, I generated figure in png format. I was required to submit a paper with the figure in 300dpi .tif format. I already converse my figure from png to tif. I know there are changes for font size or axes title, so I hope to keep one set of figure rather than one set of png and one set of tif.

Comment: If the image is a drawing, graph etc why not provide it in PDF vectorgraphics, then it is `\infty`-scalable.

Comment: Thank you José, I am using online Latex editor overleaf. After I compile the code, the error message is "Package pdftex.def Error: File `Figures/ppp-tif-converted-to.png' not found: using draft setting."  I noticed "convert program", but not sure how to use that. Can you give me a clue? Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Finally, I decide to have two sets of figures, png one for compile and attach tif one. Thanks again.