# Convert .tiff to png in latex

Tags: epstopdf, tiff

The journal I'm going to submit a paper requires `.tiff` format for images. I'm trying to add `.tiff` in latex, and I've found a thread: [Add tif image to LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89989/add-tif-image-to-latex/89993#89993).

However, I cannot add image from `.tiff`, and I don't know how to resolve it.
I just added

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{convert #1 \OutputFile}
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.tiff}{png}{.png}{convert #1 \OutputFile}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.tif,.tiff}
```

but I got a message

```
'convert' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

and error

```
'filename-tiff-to-png' not found
```

The `epstopdf` works well for `.eps` file, and my guess is that I miss something about the `convert` in the line `\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{convert #1 \OutputFile}`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick (which provides the `convert` command) installed?

Comment: I'd also recommend changing `convert` to `convert -layers flatten` in case the `.tiff`/`.tif` file has multiple layers.

Comment: Do you have to submit the .tif files in addition? Because (La)TeX cannot work natively with them: you will have to convert to either .png or .pdf at some point. It would probably be easiest if you simply did that by hand, as it were.

Comment: @frabjous I just installed ImageMagick with `convert`, but it is still not recognized. Is there anything I should do after installing ImageMagick? Thanks

Comment: @Ingmar Yes I need to submit the .tif files. Btw, it is my understanding that using the epstopdf is an easy way to automatically convert `.tif` to `.png`. Is there another way easily do that?

Comment: @Young Yes, you should be able to use the epstopdf package to call `convert` to do the conversion on the fly. With `-layers flatten` added after convert, your code above works for me (when pdflatex is called with `--shell-escape` anyway) Can you use `convert` from the command line? My guess is that LaTeX can't find `convert` because it's not in your PATH.. But I'm on Linux, and `convert` is automatically added to my PATH when I install it. Especially if you're on Windows, you may need to do some work to add the folder with the convert executable to your PATH. Post the log file if you can.

Comment: @frabjous I've added `--shell-escape` and `-layers flatten` but it still there. Also, I've tried to add path of ImageMagick to Windows Environment Variable Path, but it seems not working. You must be able to see the log file here: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgj6jg0igd3fjw6/log.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Again, can you run use convert from the command line? I'm not that familiar with MikTeX, since I use TeXlive, but you may need to do more to get shell-escape/write18 working. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37489/how-can-i-enable-write-18-on-a-miktex-installation).

Comment: @frabjous Yes, I can use `convert` from the command line, and it actually converts the image file. One thing I'm confused is that I got an error message that `convert` not found only when I added `--shell-escape` flag. Without the flag, I don't get the message but it still not converted. My understanding was that it should be opposite, right?

Comment: I guess it doesn't even try to do the conversion if `--shell-escape` isn't there. Have you tried putting the full path `C:\path\to\whatever\convert.exe` in place of `convert` in the code? (You may need to escape the backslashes.) If you're not changing the `.tiff` a lot, I would just use the `.png` you already got by converting, and save the `.tiff` as well to send to the journal.

Comment: @frabjous Wow, adding the full path in the command works. Apparently, my latex editor doesn't have access to the `convert` for some reason. I really appreciate all of your help!